# PHP - Wrong base64 hmac sha256 encoding with single or double quotes

Tags: php, base64, sha256, hmac

I am working on developping a plug-in for a payment gateway. As part the payment gateway API, I am sending several fields (e.g. amount, currency, etc. but also some plain-text fields like delivery address). I put all these in an array, the syntax is something like the below (I'm putting a simplified hard-coded version below for a sake of clarity):

```
$hidden     =   array(
            'vads_site_id'      => '1234567890',
            'vads_certificate'  => 'ABCDEFGH',
            'vads_currency'     => '978',
            'vads_amount'       => '12345',
            'vads_ship_to_street'   => $this->_basket['delivery_address']['line1']);
```

The payment gateay requires to be passed a field called "signature", which is an encryption of the concatenation of all other fields. The encryption is as the code below:

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$concatenated_string, $certificate, true));
```

As long as I don't have any single quotes (') or double quotes ("), everything works fine (even with special characters, such as "é"), and the gateway recognizes that the signature is correct. Now, whenever I input single or double quotes (and single quote is a valid character in a delivery address), I am getting something completely different. For example:

```
Expected string (UTF-8) : [tqMQ6eliAfYpBWPUf5E6QDTlTRxER1GQvIllzZ652xo=]
String received (UTF-8) : [CYrNQ4ETAFfoN9xMAy+phHEopWZQbelEOJndkQJWz8k=]
```

What really puzzles me, is that when I checked online (https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online), encoding my string with hmac sha256, with the correct certificate and output as base64, I get the correct expected string.

So I believe it's my PHP code shown above with does something wrong and wrongly interprets the quote. But to modify my code I would need to understand what exactly is wrongly interpreted in my code, and so far I haven't found it. I have tried adding a backslash before the quote ('), two or three backslashes before the quote (\', \'), I have tried stripping the string right before the quote, or right after the quote. But none of these gave me the same result as the "received string" above, so I'm still in the dark about what is wrong there.

All the plain-text fields come from a user form. I could forbid quotes in there (or remove them when contacting the gateway), but I think that wouldn't be exactly the expected behaviour.

Any hint would be highly appreciated! Cheers,
Guillaume

Comment: url encode your values

Comment: Hi Guillaume, 
Where does the user information come from ? A POST form, a database ? Maybe you've already escaped these strings and don't need to add backslash but remove it !

Comment: Hi, I've just edited my question. The problematic plain-text fields all come from a form field in by the user (I suppose POST). I considered removing them (and that would solve the problem indeed), but then the address would technically be different. I know it may not be a big deal, but the payment provider I am dealing with insisted that they shall remain.

Comment: Is it systempay ? I had to install it few month ago, and face kind of the same problem but found a solution. I can take a look at my script if so :)

Comment: It is Systempay indeed! Really appreciate if you can take a look at your script and elaborate on the fix you used!

Comment: I'm sorry i've just looked and... My solution was removing the adress and only send client mail and id (vads_cust_id), then i recovered client adress from the id with a database call. 
Passing adress is only usefull for systempay backoffice, as I already had a shop backoffice with bill and payment information it wasn't a big deal :/

Comment: Arf! The thing is I have been in touch with Systempay, and they've explicitly requested me to send this address field. So I guess I can't just remove it.

Comment: Cheers @LawrenceCherone, I have actually URL encoded (function urlencode()) the value containing a quote and it works!